# Barcode4j not working (on Unix)

Tags: java, barcode, xsl-fo, apache-fop, xalan

For my project, I need to generate a barcode for a PDF.

I have been able to successfully generate barcodes on my local Windows Server, on the production UNIX server, the generation fails though.

I use barcode4j and need to generated code39.

My template :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    xmlns:bc="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns" 
    xmlns:barcode="org.krysalis.barcode4j.xalan.BarcodeExt" 
    extension-element-prefixes="barcode"
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="versionParam" select="'1.0'"/> 

    <xsl:template match="anforderung">
        <xsl:call-template name="barcode">
        <xsl:with-param name="code" select="barcode/code" />
        <xsl:with-param name="codeoriginal" select="barcode/codeoriginal" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="barcode">
        <xsl:param name="code" />
        <xsl:param name="codeoriginal" />
        <fo:block keep-together="always">
            <!-- message für barcode -->
            <xsl:variable name="barcode-cfg">
            <barcode>
                <code39>
                    <height>16mm</height>
                    <module-width>0.3mm</module-width>
                    <human-readable>
                        <placement>none</placement>
                    </human-readable>
                </code39>
            </barcode>
            </xsl:variable>

            <fo:block font-weight="bold" margin-left="0.3in">
                <fo:table table-layout='fixed' width="100%">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="8.2cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="12cm" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                        <xsl:variable name="bc" select="barcode:generate($barcode-cfg, barcode/code)" />
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="$bc" />
                                        <!--xsl:copy-of select="barcode:generate(barcode-cfg, msg)"/-->
                                    </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="justify" font-size="32pt">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$codeoriginal" />
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

My library:

- barcode4j-fop-ext-complete-2.0
- xalan
- xercesImpl
- xml-apis
- xml-apis-ext

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get exception?

Comment: Hi AlexR,

Thank you for your reply, It show the message error in SystemErr.log like this
"Line #61; Column #79("barcode:generate(barcode-cfg, msg)"); java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/DefaultConfiguration.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V"

Kindly regards,
Eiam

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps check what version of java you are running (java -version).

Some programs do not operate properly if you are using GJC for example. In that case get OpenJDK or the Oracle JDK and try again.

Comment: Hi Danpaq,

Thank you for your reply, However I have checked java version on server already. It's same java version on local(1.6).

Do you have other idea?

Kindly regards,
Eiam

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchMethodError in the Avalon Framework class DefaultConfiguration means you may have an older Avalon Framework in the classpath. Please make sure you have Avalon Framework 4.2.0 or later. You can find it in Barcode4J's lib directory.